# Passing boolean value is not getting shared from one component to another - Angular

Tags: angular, eventemitter

This is just simple usecase, but don't get what I'm missing.

I've componentA & componentB. Passing booloan value via click event from **componentB** to **componentA** using **eventEmitter**, to show/hide particular div in componentA.

So far

### componentB

```
public showLayOut = false;
@Output() passThisValue = new EventEmitter<boolean>();

ngOnInit(): void {
    this.showLayOut = false;
}

triggerEventToPassBoolVal() {

    this.someService(baseLink).subscribe((data) => {
        if (data[0].status === true) {
            this.showLayOut = true;
            if (this.showLayOut) {
                this.passThisValue.emit(this.showLayOut);
            }
        }
    })
}
```

### componentA.html

```
<div *ngIf="showLayOut">
   <p>Show this div if emitted value is true, otherwise hide</p>
</div>
```

Could anyone pls help me to point out what i did wrong ?, if possible pls share any existing stackblitz working sample

Note: im using form like this to submit data `(ngSubmit)="OK(data)"`
Thanks

Comment: Can you share your codes to stackblitz, and paste the link here.

Comment: @truonghungit https://stackblitz.com/edit/angular-ivy-v9spro?file=src%2Fapp%2Fchild%2Fchild.component.html here in stackblitz there is an error. but i dont see that in my project

Comment: @worstCoder, Do you need like this? https://stackblitz.com/edit/angular-ivy-zatwqo

Comment: @ManirajMurugan thanks for the headsup. but im doing the same when submitting the form. i've updated my question.

Comment: @worstCoder, I couldn't see any code related to form.. Can you update the stackblitz with code related to form? So that it will be easy to understand your real problem..

Comment: @ManirajMurugan thanks for your time.. i fixed my issue, its due to im sending FALSE inside one if condition thus cause the issue

Comment: @worstCoder, You could see that in my stackblitz itself that I have removed that condition already.. Anyhow glad to hep you thanks..

Answer (score 0):

If **componentA** is parent component of **componentB**. I have that solution. for ex:

```
  import { Component, OnInit, ViewContainerRef } from '@angular/core';
  
  // componentB.compoent.ts

  getParentComponent() {
    return this.viewContainerRef['_data'].componentView.component.viewContainerRef['_view'].component;
  }
  
  changeBooleanvalueMethod () {
     this.getParentComponent().showLayOut = true; // showLayOut is componentA variable
  }
```